# How to add booting parameters to the kernel with bcfg from the EFI shell?

Tags: linux, boot, efi

`efibootmgr` is creating invalid entries in the EFI boot menu. For instance `efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdX -p Y -l /EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi -L "rEFInd Boot Manager"` adds an unbootable japanese characters in the boot menu.

On the other hand `bcfg boot add 3 fs0:\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi "rEFInd"` works just fine.

Now I would like to boot directly onto `vmlinuz-linux` instead of passing through `refind`. Does anyone have an idea on how to pass parameters to the kernel ? Without the paramaters it's : `bcfg boot add 3 fs0:\vmlinuz-linux  "linux"` but what option do I need to use to add `initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=/dev/sda2` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar issues on one particular (Supermicro) motherboard, and while Steve's suggestion of using a text file works, there's a bit more nuance. I've tried to document the process below:

1. If you don't have `bcfg` available, you first need to get a copy of an EFI 2.x shell. The motherboard firmware probably has 1.x. The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Obtaining_UEFI_Shell) has more details, but for *most* 64-bit modern systems you'll want to grab the `Shell.efi` from [here](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/master/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64) and rename it `shellx64.efi` and place it directly in the root of your EFI System Partition. If your motherboard provides a `Launch EFI Shell from filesystem device`, use it. Otherwise, you can use the built-in shell to launch the updated shell. See the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Launching_UEFI_Shell) for further information.
2. Once you're in the 2.x shell, you'll want to make sure your boot option exists. You can list options with `bcfg boot dump -b` (the `-b` enables the pager, like `more`). If it does not exist, you'll need to add one, preferably to the top of the list. You can browse around - list filesystems with `map -b`, look for entries starting with `fs` like `fs0:`, and then use `ls` like `ls fs0:\`, `ls fs0:\EFI\`, etc to explore the directories.

   Once you find the bootloader's path (and the correct `fs` device), add it (as in the original question):

   ```
   bcfg boot add 3 fs0:\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi "rEFInd"
   ```

   This adds it as the 4th boot entry (counting from 0, 1, 2, 3)
3. Once you have the boot option added (verify with `bcfg boot dump -b`) you need to add the optional data (boot parameters). As Steve briefly mentioned, the most robust way to do this is by saving these params to a file and then importing them with `bcfg -opt`. However, from what I can tell, this **appends** the options, so you're best off `bcfg boot rm`ing the boot option first and readding it as per step 2. Once you have a clean entry, you can add the optional data. For example:

   ```
   edit fs0:\EFI\refind\options.txt
   ```

   This will open a file editor. Type in your options (on a single line), and press F2 to save. Press F3 to exit. You can also edit this file from within an OS, but you **must** save it as UTF-16 (LE, little-endian). The EFI Shell's editor does that automatically.

   The next step is to import the options:

   ```
   bcfg boot -opt 3 fs0:\EFI\refind\options.txt
   ```

   Again, the `3` specifies the boot entry. This should match the one you added it as. Do not run this command multiple times - you must `rm` and re-`add` the entry before you can change options.
4. Verify the boot options and optional data with `bcfg boot dump -v -b`.

Answer (score 2):

I am encountering the same situation. I believe the solution will involve the use of the -opt parameter either in-line with the add or as an additional command. So far though I have not had success putting all of the parameters in a quoted string. My next attempt will be to create a file using edit and passing the filename using -opt.

If you succeed, please update this thread.

So, in the uefi shell I used edit to create an opt file on the media at the same location as the kernel. In it I placed the kernel options on a single line. I then used the command bcfg boot -opt 0 FS0:\filename You may need to use a different FS number, -opt number and filename to match your configuration.

Comment: Referring to a file works, but you have to be careful to remove and recreate the entry in between attempts - at least on my motherboard, using the file only **appends** entries, it does not replace existing ones. I've added an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1216115/117590) to try to document the full process.

Answer (score 0):

The first command you typed is correct. You add options with another command. For your specific case, it is:

```
Shell> bcfg boot -opt 3 "initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=/dev/sda2"
```

Comment: This gives me the error `bcfg: Invalid argument - 'initrd initrd=\initramfs-linux.img root=/dev/sda2'`

Comment: Same for me, Gigabyte X370 K7 motherboard, for reference.

Answer (score 0):

My documentation for `efibootmgr` shows that `-p` is for specifying the partition number, but in your question it looks like you're using `Y` for the value. If that wasn't a typo, it could explain why you get strange characters in the menu and had trouble booting.

As for passing parameters, there's a switch `-@` which escaped my attention the first couple times I read the docs. If you supply a file name, it'll read a line of parameters from that file.

The docs also say you can use `-` as the file name, but when I tried that, I wasn't able to get it to proceed after inputting text; pressing `enter` or `^D` seemed to have no effect, while `^C` terminated the program without making changes.

---

If you wish to experiment in a VM before messing with your hardware, the following may be helpful - though you'll need to adjust the OVMF paths for your distro:

- Install qemu and the ovmf firmware package.
- Copy `/usr/share/edk2-ovmf/OVMF_VARS.fd` to the current directory - qemu will write efi config changes to this file.
- Create a directory for qemu to use as Virtual VFAT (`vvfat`). I'll refer to it as `hda` from now on.
- Copy a kernel which has the EFI stub into `hda`.
- If that kernel doesn't have an embedded initrd with a shell and `efibootmgr`, locate or build an initrd which does, and place it in `hda`. (A generic initrd may work, since those generally let you enter an emergency mode if they can't find the root volume.)
- start qemu; I use the following command:

  ```
  qemu-system-x86_64 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,readonly=on,file=/usr/share/edk2-ovmf/OVMF_CODE.fd -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1,readonly=off,file=OVMF_VARS.fd -enable-kvm -cpu host -m 1024 -usb -device usb-tablet -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -hda fat:rw:hda -boot menu=on
  ```

  - Once booted, do not modify the `hda` dir from outside the VM - see the warning [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Devices/Storage).
  - Note the `-boot menu=on` part. If necessary, you can press `ESC` while it's booting, and you'll get into the uefi config. From there, you can boot particular entries or create/delete/edit.
- You'll drop into an EFI Shell if it doesn't find a file to boot.

  - From there, you could use `bcfg` to view/edit entries.
  - Or, you could boot your linux kernel:

    ```
    fs0:
    bzImage.efi initrd=\absolute\path\to\initrd arg arg arg
    ```
  - ...at which point the kernel should load and boot with the provided initrd and args. Note that an absolute path is mandatory when using initrd - see [efi-stub.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/efi-stub.txt)
  - Now, you can poke around in the efi files under `/sys/firmware/`, try out `efibootmgr`, etc... all without risking your real hardware. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this instead of `/dev/sda` you must also use `partuuid` or `uuid` like this:

```
--disk /dev/sdX --part Y --create --label "Arch Linux" --loader /vmlinuz-linux --unicode 'root=PARTUUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX rw initrd=\initramfs-linux.img' --verbose
```

Comment: remeber you escape chars when your adding those lines in esp for linux for me it was /vmlinuz-linux would be \\vmlinuz-linux